# Обобщенный JSON

Tags: java, json, gson

Сервер присылает ответы в формате

```
{response: {.......}}
```

например

```
{response: {code: 0}}
{response: {type: "test"}}
```

Пытаюсь сделать парсинг при помощи библиотеки gson в таком виде

```
class Response<T> {
    private T response;
    public T getResponse() {
        return response;
    }
}

class CodeInfo {
    private int code;
}

class TypeInfo {
    private String type;
}

<T> T parse(String str) {
  Response<T> resp = gson.fromJson(str, Response<T>.class);
  return resp.getResponse();
}

CodeInfo = parse<CodeInfo>("{response: {code: 0}}");
```

Внутренние классы довольно обширные

На конструкции `Response<T>.class` компилятор меня посылает. Решается ли задача без кучи наследников `Response<T>`? В принципе, могу даже сменить парсер

Comment: Либо делаете один класс с двумя полями code и type. Либо два класса, а потом анализируете содержимое json-а и выбираете в какой класс мапить. Если вы заранее знаете что у вас в json (как например в последней строке вашего кода), то просто выносите из класса метод parse и добавляйте ему в атрибуты нужный класс: public static <T> T parse(String str, Class<T> clazz) {return gson.fromJson(str, clazz);}

Comment: @Russtam Два поля не вариант. Внутренние классы довольно обширные. Передать ссылку на класс можно, но вопрос в том, что у меня меняется внутренний класс, а ссылку нужно передавать на внешний

Comment: может добавить ещё один аргумент в функцию `parse`, в который передавать `new TypeToken<Response<****Info>>(){}.getType()`, где вместо `****` ставить `Code` или `Type`. Функция `parse` будет передавать этот аргумент в `fromJson`

Comment: @diraria А нельзя передавать просто `CodeInfo.class`, а в функции `parse` уже вызывать `new TypeToken<Response<InClass>>(){}.getType()`?

Comment: ни разу так не делал, но кажется подходит [этот ответ на enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44303941/5812238). Там вместо `List.class` `Response.class`, а вместо `myType` параметр метода, `****Info.class`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Спасибо @diraria за направление на путь истинный. Итого получилось

```
public <T> T parse(String str, Class<T> AClass) {
  Response<T> resp = JSON.fromJson(
    str,
    TypeToken.getParameterized(Response.class, AClass).getType()
  );
  return resp.getResponse();
}

CodeInfo info = parse("{response: {code: 0}}", CodeInfo.class)
```

Если писать так

```
public <T> T parse(String str) {
  Response<T> resp = JSON.fromJson(
    str,
    new TypeToken<Response<T>>(){}.getType()
  );
  return resp.getResponse();
}
```

то строка парсится, но `resp.getResponse()` возвращает объект класса   `com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap`

Answer (score 1):

`public <T> T parse(String str)` возвращает `LinkedTreeMap`, потому что `T` существует буквально только в воображении компилятора, и поэтому во время исполнения Gson не имеет достаточно информации о типе (заметьте, я сказал "тип", а не "класс"), которым параметризируется `Response`.
У `public <T> T parse(String str, Class<T> AClass)` тоже проблемы, потому что объекты `java.lang.Class` не содержат информации о параметризации (так, впрочем, реализованы обобщённые типы в Java).
Вследствие чего `Response<T>.class` просто не имеет смысла (`Class` предоставляет информацию только о загруженном классе или о прититивном типе!), и поэтому компилятор ожидает `Response.class` (хотя, я думаю, что в Java можно было бы ввести что-то типа `Response<T>.type`, определявший объект `ParameterizedType`; если я не ошибаюсь, аналогичная возможность есть в Kotlin).
`ParameterizedType`, используемый Gson-ом на всю катушку, позволяет сохранять информацию о параметризации типа.
Т.е., скорее нужно иметь следующую реализацию:

```java
private static <T> T parse(final String json, final java.lang.reflect.Type type) {
    final Response<T> response = gson.fromJson(json, TypeToken.getParameterized(Response.class, type).getType());
    return response.response;
}
```

В этом случае, появляется возможность передавать в метод тип со сколь угодно сложной параметеризацией -- достаточно реализации интерфейса.
Я, правда, уже не помню, есть ли в Gson готовые методы, позволяющие конструировать информацию о типах, не используя свои реализации.
Но сам по себе `Type` не имеет сильного контроля типов, что чревато неприятными ошибками во время исполнения (например, `ParameterizedType.getActualTypeArguments`, возвращающий примитивный тип или неоответствие между типом переменной-приёмником и типом, описуемым `ParameterizedType`).

Во избежение неприятностей и для ужесточения контроля типов в Gson имеется `TypeToken` (имеет аналоги в Google Guava, Jackson и Spring Framework под другими именами).
Его задача -- содержать полную информацию о типе, определяемой ещё на этапе компиляции, что позволяет использовать компилятор для контроля типов.
Сам `TypeToken` является абстрактным классом, заставляя в субклассах определять параметризацию, которую можно прочитать во время выполнения.
И, как по мне, это позволяет весьма элегантно обходить ограничения, связанные с затиранием информации об обобщённых типах в Java:

```java
private static final TypeToken<Response<CodeInfo>> responseCodeInfoTypeToken = new TypeToken<Response<CodeInfo>>() {
};

...
    final CodeInfo codeInfo = parse("{response: {code: 1230}}", responseCodeInfoTypeToken);
    assert codeInfo.code == 1230;
...

private static <T> T parse(final String json, final TypeToken<Response<T>> typeToken) {
    final Response<T> response = gson.fromJson(json, typeToken.getType());
    return response.response;
}
```

`TypeToken` можно закешировать в статическом поле, он иммутабелен.