# Как достать вложенные объекты из json через gson

Tags: java, gson

Как достать key?

```
{
  "response": {
    "key": "text"
  }
}
```

Comment: Так? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/763102/221228

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
JsonObject obj = new Gson().fromJson(jsonStr, JsonObject.class);
String result = obj.getAsJsonObject("response")
                   .get("key")
                   .toString();
```

Comment: Да, это оно, а десириализировать сразу все объекты из response{} можно? Их там несколько

Comment: В смысле? У response несколько дочерних элементов и вы хотите получить их них Map?

Comment: Map? НУ я насколько знаю с помощью reflection'a в gson можно сразу все объекты которые есть в json перенести в java переменные, я имелл ввиду это.

Comment: Это очень-очень плохая идея. Вы получите медленную и нестабильную программу, которую стыдно показывать коллегам и опасно работодателю.

Comment: Хорошо, сделаю иначе.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, описать внутренний объект

```
class A {
  B response;
}

class B {
  String key;
}
```

Или через внутренний класс

```
class A {
  private static class B {
    String key;
  }
  B response;
}
```

Использование:

```
A resp = gson.fromJson(data, A.class);
System.out.println(resp.response.key);
```

Comment: Да, но не хочется этого делать, есть возможность сделать это иначе?

Comment: @Евгений почему не хочется?