# Как парсить с помощью gson суб классы разно типа?

Tags: java, gson

Получаю с сервера ответ Обьект с общим полем доступным для наследникок result   и 2 типа данных дата 
1)Это  здесь поле data это обьект с почтовым адресом

```
 {
  "operationResult": "true",
  "class": "Person",
  "data": {
    "email": "email"
  }
}
```

2) здесь это массив

```
{
  "operationResult": "true",
  "className": "OperationList",
  "data": [
        {
            "orderId": "aacccdd"
       } 
         ]
}
```

Как правильно спарсить эти данные взависимости от data c помощью Gson?

Comment: Вы знаете какой пакет вам придет или нет? Если знаете, то ответ вот https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/763004/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-json/763102#763102